# How much data amount could Rstudio read

Tags: r, csv

I am using R to handle large amount of data in different years. My computer is MACpro with processor 2.4GHz, memory 8GB.

Now I opend two R sessions on my computer, and I have read large amount of data into them, like one csv file 1.27GB. I used fread() to read them and then manipulate. It works good so far.

But just a moment before, I use fread() to read a csv file with 4.72GB and it read slowly but stops at 64.1% for more than 2 mins. So I just stopped it.

I want to ask: how much data could Rstudio read in with my computer? Is there a general limit? If I clean the data stored in Global Environment, which would be more than 3GB, would I be able to read the new 4.72GB file?

Thank you!

Comment: At the scales you're dealing with the only limit is the amount of RAM in your machine. So yes, if you clear the 3GB from your workspace and verify through a program like Activity Monitor or `ctop` that that memory is really free, you should have no problem loading that 4.72GB file. Just make sure you don't have other memory-hungry applications open, like Chrome with lots of tabs that haven't been closed in a long time.

Comment: @jon_simon Thank you! I actually have a further one. When I delete the large dataset, like 2GB, from global environment, the memory is occupied like before? Do you know why would this happen and what could I do to emend this except restarting Rstudio?

Comment: I've encountered this same issue before with R. I've never found a perfect solution, but I have found that in cases where programs refuse to release memory that they're no longer using, the `purge` terminal command can help

Comment: @jon_simon, thanks! I just want to make sure that: I open the terminal, and then enter `purge`, that's it? I am afraid if I understand it wrong, other needed files might be deleted... :)

Comment: You will likely need to run `sudo purge`. Follow the directions here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/24/free-up-inactive-memory-in-mac-os-x-with-purge-command/